# Recharts - add commas to number on tooltip on bar chart

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, recharts

Is it possible to add a comma to large numbers on the tooltip?

for example 
57,574 instead of 57574

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: check here https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/663

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you can pass any formatter function to the Tooltip component, using the `formatter` prop e.g.

```
<BarChart>
  <Tooltip formatter={(value) => new Intl.NumberFormat('en').format(value)} />
</BarChart>
```

Check out the documentation here: http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Tooltip#formatter

Comment: do you have a typescript example?

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter and without calling Intl

```
<BarChart>
  <Tooltip formatter={(value) => value && value.toLocaleString()} />
</BarChart>
```